# WebSocket: Invalid frame header while connecting

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome

I'm trying to connect to a local server using `WebSockets`. On my `C#` app using `WebSocketSharp` I do this to send data to the socket:

```
    using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3344/socket"))
    {
        // Receive data from WebSocket
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Code ...
        };

        ws.Connect();
        ws.Send(data);
    }
```

This works perfectly, I can send data and receive the response from the `WebSocket`. Now, I'm trying to do the same in Javascript:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3344/socket");
```

Just with this line I'm getting the error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3344/socket' failed: Invalid frame header`. I'm using Chrome 49 running this inside an Angular app. I searched over Google and found that this is maybe a problem in the server side but why my `C#` can connect?

I'm trying to connect to [Repetier Server](http://www.repetier-server.com/manuals/programming/API/index.html%20%22%22). The only information I have is that requests must be smaller then 8kb and UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Take a look at same issue at WebSocketSharp github repo: https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/120

Comment: _"Now, I'm trying to do the same in Javascript"_ - you do realize that the C# code runs on the server (`localhost` pointing to the server) and that JS runs on the client (`localhost` pointing to the client)?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, but in my case the server and client are on the same PC